UserWarning scipy.stats.shapiro
I get this error using shapiro wilks test for normality.
UserWarning: scipy.stats.shapiro: For N > 5000, computed p-value may not be accurate. Current N is 1048575.   stat, p  = st.shapiro(householdPowerConsumption_analysis.Global_active_power
I'm looking for a solution.

Can you clarify what kind of solution you're looking for? Do you want to suppress the warning, get a more accurate p-value, etc?

I am not sure a p-value on normality is helpful here. The power consumption is definitely not normally distributed. This graph looks bi-modal: https://github.com/mkivenson/Household-Power-Consumption/blob/master/Energy_Analysis.ipynb

This is my code
stat, p  = st.shapiro(householdPowerConsumption_analysis.Global_active_power)
print(p)
if p > 0.05 :
print('Sample looks Gaussian/Normal (We fail to reject H0)')
else:
print('Samples does not look Gaussian/Normal(reject H0)')
I'm trying to say if p > 0.05 , print graph looks like normal distribution else print graph dont look like normal distribution . The code runs but i get the above userwwarning

If you must perform the Shapiro-Wilk test, you can use the statistic produced by shapiro but estimate the p-value using monte_carlo_test.
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng()

def statistic(x):
    return stats.shapiro(x).statistic

x = rng.normal(size=1000)  # generate example data
res = stats.monte_carlo_test(x, rng.normal, statistic, 
                             alternative='less', batch=10)
ref = stats.shapiro(x)
res.pvalue, ref.pvalue
# (0.3355, 0.3304923474788666)

This is exlained in the documentation of shapiro. It will take a while for samples as large as yours.
You can also choose any one of the other normality tests in SciPy:
skewtest, kurtosistest, normaltest, jarque_bera, and anderson. IIRC, the p-values of all of these get more accurate as the sample size increases.
(Of course, there are several other more general goodness of fit tests that could be used, but you might as well use one tailored for normality since there are so many available.)
